# How do I reference SSIS on a build machine without installing SQL Server 2008 Client Tools?

Tags: sql-server, configuration, ssis, build-automation

I need to build SSIS packages on a build machine, and do not want the overhead of installing SQL Server Management Studio on this machine. A SQL Server 2008 SDK would be ideal, but I could not find where to download it.

The dlls I require are (for example):

- Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS
- Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost
- Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap
- Microsoft.SQLServer.DTSRuntimeWrap

I could attempt to copy them to the build machine individually, but I would rather just use an SDK if possible.

Where can I get the SDK, or alternatively, what suggestions are there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably manually copy things about and register then in the GAC, but the client tools are hardly huge, and don't take long to install, so I don't see why they are much of an overhead?

As far as I know there's no other way to get those assemblies.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer as I had a good look for an SDK that contains these assemblies and came up with nothing. Looks like SSMS is required to build SSIS components.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about SQL 2008 but SQL 2005 SSIS packages are developed in Visual Studio.

Edited:
When you run install for client tools, it's an option to add the stuff to VS.NET, "Client tools" as such can be deselected (end edit)

SSMS can be used to manage them and administer.

What other editor did you want to use...?

Comment: I think his point was that he didn't want to install the client tools. Although I'm not quite sure why :)

Comment: YOu're right,,, not as clear as I wanted. One could run the install but deselect SSMS etc (what we perceive to be "client tools").

Comment: I wanted to configure a build machine with the minimum software required to build SSIS components. The SSMS is a front end component that will never be run on the build machine. I would far rather an SDK with just the assemblies I require. However, it looks like this is not available.

Comment: By the time you install VS, SSMS would be the least of your worries :-)
There is no alternative editor to replace VS whether you run the SQL install or roll your own SSIS assemblies somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I think he is trying to accomplish SSIS packages as part of the automated continuous build process. The way i did it was to have an express edition of SQL Server and SSIS on the build machine, use BIDS helper to script the cmd line file for deploying the packages and use NANT to use this script. Hope this helped.